# Iterating through nested element in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with following schema :-

```
scala> final_df.printSchema
root
 |-- mstr_prov_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prov_ctgry_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prov_orgnl_efctv_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- prov_trmntn_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- prov_trmntn_rsn_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- npi_rqrd_ind: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prov_stts_aray_txt: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- PROV_STTS_KEY: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PROV_STTS_EFCTV_DT: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PROV_STTS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PROV_STTS_TRMNTN_DT: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PROV_STTS_TRMNTN_RSN_CD: string (nullable = true)
```

I am running following code to do basic cleansing but its not working inside "prov_stts_aray_txt" , basically its not going inside array type and performing transformation desire. I want to iterate through out nested all fields(Flat and nested field within Dataframe and perform basic transformation.

```
for(dt <- final_df.dtypes){
  final_df = final_df.withColumn(dt._1,when(upper(trim(col(dt._1))) === "NULL",lit(" ")).otherwise(col(dt._1)))
}
```

please help.

Thanks

Comment: What following code?

Comment: @stefanobaghino I have updated code. Can you please help over